# jsPDF not rendering html element with -v 1.2.61(IE)/ giving 110 error in adobe viewer with -v 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, jspdf, html2canvas

I am facing a tricky problem with jsPDF. I have added two images(one is logo and another one is a highchart), html content as part of the document.
Here is the problem based on jsPDF version

```
When jsPDF version 1.2.61
```

Pdf download works fine for all browser except IE, It ignores html text content in dowloaded pdf.

```
When jsPDF version 1.3.2
```

In Adobe viewer it gives error 110.

I have tried some of the suggestions provided by the community and also created a working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LTZHOc?p=preview) of the same still can't able to get through it.
Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

**Note:** What I guess is that the image that I am using in top(logo) is causing the issue, as when I remove that everything works fine for all browser with both version of jsPDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out the solution to this problem. Have looked into [jsPDF issues](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/862). Thanks to @**Pe46dro** comment on this issue.
The problem is related to png compression in Adobe Reader which the community members have resolved but I guess not yet released.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue. USing to jsPDF version 1.3.4 solved it.